# How can I locate an element with specific text in it?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

The `label` is the element I'm trying to locate, and the text I know is `Cost of paving parking lot in front of building`.

I tried `contains`, `innerText()`, and `textContent()`

Comment: Hi @elephish remember to use images only when you can't attach your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the  with respect to the `<p>` element containing the text *Cost of paving parking lot in front of building* you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* with respect to `<p>` tag:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(., 'Cost of paving parking lot in front of building')]//ancestor::label[@class='ahe-ui-radio']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* with respect to child tags:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='ahe-ui-radio' and @for][.//p[contains(., 'Cost of paving parking lot in front of building')]]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath should match all `label` elements that have descendant node with tag `p` containing your text. Try if it works for your problem.

```
label_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[.//p[contains(text, 'Cost of paving parking lot in front of building.')]]")
```